# Using reflection to know fields and the relative values

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection to know fields and relative values of a Class (MyClass).

So far I did this, but this allow me to know just the fields and relative type (String, int etc) and not the values by me:

```
    MyClass myClassFromDB = <--- I filled this object by making a query with hibernate
    Class <?> myClass= myClassFromDB.getClass();        
    Field [] fieldList= myClass.getDeclaredFields();        

    for(Field field: fieldList){            
            System.out.println(field.getName()+": "+myClass.getDeclaredField(field.getName()));             
    }
```

I thought that using `getDeclaredField()` I would get the values of those fields, but I get just something like this `private java.lang.Integer package.className.FieldName`

Comment: This code you tried and left out might be interesting in finding out why it didn't work...

Comment: Can't you simply check if the object is not null?

Comment: Try singleField.get(filledMyClass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to get the field values you need to use like this

```
for(Field field: fieldList){            
    try {

        // Will return field value of object type, you need to cast it to the required type. For identifying the object type you can use 'instanceof' keyword.            
        Object object = myClass.getDeclaredField(field.getName()).get(myClassFromDB);

        System.out.println("object :: "+object);

        if(object instanceof String){
            System.out.println("val :: "+(String)object);
        } // Similarily you can do it for other types.

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        System.out.println("IllegalArgumentException :: "+ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        System.out.println("IllegalAccessException :: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

`get(instance)` -- will return the field value associated with the field.